# If I resign before my annual bonus is paid, will I get it anyway?

Tags: resignation, bonus

My company will pay bonuses at the end of May. If I resign before that, are there any chances of still receiving it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I be concerned about my bonus when putting in notice?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20489/should-i-be-concerned-about-my-bonus-when-putting-in-notice)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it naive to tell my current employer that I'll be leaving, months in advance?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6840/is-it-naive-to-tell-my-current-employer-that-ill-be-leaving-months-in-advance)

Comment: Hey gotch4, and welcome to [workplace.se]! Your question is quite short and doesn't explain your concern very clearly -- why would you think you would/wouldn't get it currently? What are the conditions/background of the bonus? If you could [edit] your question to explain more clearly what the situation is, it will be automatically reviewed by the community for reopening. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

**Check your contract** - there's no real way for us to know.

Typically, humans are notorious for not wanting to part with money they don't have to, so I'd imagine the likely answer is "no, you probably won't get the bonus".

If you know any employees at your company who you trust to be discreet, you could ask them if there have been similar situations in the past, and find out how they were handled.

Comment: Just as an anecdote, a friend and former coworker of mine put in his notice in January. When April rolled around and we got our bonus from the previous year, he received his as well. Might not be the case for you, but it can happen.